# Missing content in an unstored Solr field

Tags: solr

We have a schema defined as such:

```xml
<schema name="project" version="1.6">
  <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" />
  <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />

  <field name="full_content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" />

  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" />
  <fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true"/>

  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
</schema>
```

The `qf` (via eDismax) is set to `full_content`.

We have a nightly job that imports new documents from last 24 hours. 
Recently, we noticed that we couldn't find certain documents in a free search. 
After some digging we concluded that some Solr documents (some, as in 200K of the 3M Solr documents) have no `full_content` filled in.

We tried to debug this in our importer-application, but all that is available and fetched right up until we send it to Solr. From there on, we have no idea what Solr is doing with it.

Why are some `full_content` fields empty? No logs, no errors .. no clue.

What could be the cause of this?

- Memory issues? We checked the size of some missing `full_content` fields and they are not that large.
- Is that a possible behaviour of unstored fields? Should we store the `full_content`?

Solr: 7.6.0

Comment: According to your schema `full_content` is already set to stored? .. `stored="true"`. If  a field isn't stored (unless it has support for using DocValues as stored, which a text field doesn't), it won't return anything. That's what `stored` means - that the actual text is stored in addition to the tokens, so that the actual content can be retrieved when requested.

Comment: @MatsLindh sorry, that was a mistake in the question. It is **unstored**. I know unstored fields won't return anything. But I know some are empty because searching for specific words that I know are inside `full_content` returns not the expected result.

Comment: A trick you can use is to query for the specific id, then add a facet on `full_content`. It should return all the generated tokens for that document. If nothing is returned, then there was, for some reason, no content indexed for the full content field at all. That can be caused by an encoding issue for the documents field values - i.e. what's being returned isn't valid utf-8 before indexing, and thus the content is dropped. Another thing is that you don't need separate index/query analyzers if they're identical - just define them once without `type`.